# RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance

Tags: laravel, node-modules, yarn-v2

I hope you are doing well
I have developed a project that I want to put online but I am encountering problems.
The project is made with laravel and tailwindcss and contains node and vendor dependencies.
I retrieve the project from gitlab which I clone on the oswitch cpanel using the http link
The configuration of Laravel is done without problem (configuration of the .env, generation of migrations, etc.)
The problem occurs when I run yarn run buid
[Voici l'erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHSH7.jpg)
I've been having this problem for 5 days now and I can't find a solution.
I really need a helping hand
THANKS

My research led me to understand that the problem is related to the process not having enough space to run. Except that I still have enough space on my accommodation.
Initially I worked with npm but when the problem arose, several people advised me to go back to yarn, which I did but the problem persisted.
However locally, I have no problem with the project.
I tried to send the node module from my local to the cpanel, but there was a conflict because the environments are different (I work locally under Windows and the cpanel is Linux)
So I had to reinstall the node module on the cpanel.